# Syntax unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php

```
function secondsToTime($inputSeconds) {

   $secondsInAMinute = 60;
   $secondsInAnHour  = 60 * $secondsInAMinute;
   $secondsInADay    = 24 * $secondsInAnHour;

    $days = floor($inputSeconds / $secondsInADay);

   $hourSeconds = $inputSeconds % $secondsInADay;
   $hours = floor($hourSeconds / $secondsInAnHour);

    $minuteSeconds = $hourSeconds % $secondsInAnHour;
    $minutes = floor($minuteSeconds / $secondsInAMinute);


    $remainingSeconds = $minuteSeconds % $secondsInAMinute;
    $seconds = ceil($remainingSeconds);

    $obj = array(
        'd' => (int) $days,
        'h' => (int) $hours,
        'm' => (int) $minutes,
        's' => (int) $seconds
    );

    return $obj;
}
```

this function give's me an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 6
```

i call it like this:

```
$start = new DateTime('2010-10-12');
$end = new DateTime('2010-10-14');
$seconds = round(abs($end->format('U') - $start->format('U')));
$obj = secondsToTime($seconds);
```

Comment: Aside from the missing comment in the posted code, line six has no strings.  Post the code where you call this function

Comment: sorry for that error, updated, its still give'me that error

Comment: if I put that in a clean php file, starting from the beginning it will be near the $secondsInAMinute = 60; - and i dont know what it can be, maybe some BOM??

Comment: Then start at that line and backspace over the whitespace until you find the errant non-printable character.

Comment: wow), i've copid it from here stackoverflow textarea to my redactor and it worked))), it looks like there was some invisible symbols and here they was deleted))

Comment: are you copy/pasting or typing the code above?

Comment: -1. Line #6 of ***which*** file? Did you look at the code and tried something before posting the question?

Answer (score 3):

Unless it's a typo in your example, you didn't comment `extract the remaining seconds`, you need to add `//` before it:

```
// extract the remaining seconds
```

Comment: Then that function is not the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I testet your code and it obviously works.

However, I have come across a similar issue a while ago. My code worked locally but when uploaded to a server it throw "Unexpected T_STRING...". After many hours I found out that the charset was changed and some random extra characters were inserted in the beginning of my script file.

Don't know if this is applicable in your case or if it will help you. But you could try open your file in a good text editor to check the charset and unexpected characters.